# DataGrid row selection won't trigger property changed

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selecteditem, propertychanged

i have a datagrid, when i select a row the property that is bound to selected item is being called correctly but if if i click on the same row again(unselect it) property changed is not called.
any idea why?
the ItemsSource object implement INotifyPropertyChaqnged and the property in the VM is standard and as i said it works just not when i unselect a row.
here is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid
     CanUserAddRows="False"
     CanUserDeleteRows="False"
     CanUserReorderColumns="False"
     GridLinesVisibility="None"
     ItemsSource="{Binding AllChannelsRecordingSchedule,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChannelRecordingServer,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     AlternatingRowBackground="{StaticResource VigilantDataGridAlternatingRowColor}"
     ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource VigilantDataGridColumnHeader}"
     RowBackground="White"
     RowHeaderWidth="0"
     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     FontFamily="Arial"
     FontSize="14"
     MaxWidth="805"
     Height="350"
     Background="White">
     <DataGrid.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
               <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
               <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
          </Style>
     </DataGrid.Resources>
          <DataGrid.RowStyle>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000" />
                             </Trigger>
                             <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000" />
                               </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn
                            Header="{x:Static p:Resources.SystemRecordingSchedule_ServerName}"
                            Width="*"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Binding="{Binding ServerName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>

                        <DataGridTextColumn
                            Header="{x:Static p:Resources.SystemRecordingSchedule_ServerIP}"
                            MinWidth="120"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Binding="{Binding ServerIP,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>

                        <DataGridTextColumn
                            Header="{x:Static p:Resources.SystemRecordingSchedule_ChannelName}"
                            MinWidth="150"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            Binding="{Binding ChannelName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn
                            Header="00:00       06:00       12:00       18:00       24:00"
                            MinWidth="350"
                            IsReadOnly="True">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <userControls:SchedulerControl
                                        FullRecordingSchedule="{Binding FullRecordingSchedule,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        IsEnabled="False"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First fix the code sample formatting
Not one wants to look to the right

Your assumption that a second click unselects is not valid

The property is SelectedItem (not SelectedUnselectedItem)

The second click just re-selects and and since it is already selected the UI fires nothing

Even if you had a selection changed event it would not fire on a second select.

If you want something for Select / Unselect you could use a CheckBox column

Comment: i know exactly how SelectedItem Works, thing is if you look at the DataGrid triggers you would see it colors the row's background to blue when the item IsSelected property is set to true, and that trigger works.
it looks a little odd to me that SelectedItem property of the DataGrid and IsSelcted of the DataGridRow are not synched.

Comment: You question and comment does not indicate to me that you know how SelectedItems works.

Comment: obviously you don't have an answer, and besides some event is fired and causes the row background to change.

Comment: So a color changed?  From that you assume a second click should un-select even though it does not un-select and that is not the documented behavior.  SOLID LOGIC.

Comment: did i say that in my comment or is that just what you want to read? i simply wrote "some event is fired and causes the row background to change"...

Comment: But the question is about SelectedItem.   Then what does color change have to do with the stated question?   What about there is no unselect on a second click is not an answer to the question as stated?